# Set YUM versionlock, but allow updating to specific versions

Tags: puppet, yum

I am trying to control the version of puppet agent installed on our RedHat systems.

Our Puppet manifest has

```
$puppet_version = hiera('profile::puppet_agent::version', '6.12.0')

class {'::puppet_agent':
  collection            => 'puppet6',
  package_version       => $puppet_version,
  service_names         => [], # Don't start puppet service
  msi_move_locked_files => true,
  manage_pki_dir        => false,
}

# This is required on RedHat 7 only
$puppet_release = $::osreleasemaj ? {
  '7'     => '*.el7.*',
  default => undef,
}

yum::versionlock { 'puppet-agent':
  ensure  => present,
  version => $puppet_version,
  release => $puppet_release,
  before  => Class['Puppet_agent'],
}
```

This works to configure `puppet` and it actually changes the contents of the YUM versionlock config file, but it doesn't seem to work to force `puppet-agent` to upgrade. I changed the version from `6.12.0` to `6.16.0`. Now every puppet run fails with the error message `Could not update: Failed to update to version 6.16.0, got version 6.12.0-1.el7 instead`.

On RHEL 7, `/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/versionlock.list` contains:

```
# File managed by puppet
0:puppet-agent-6.16.0-*.el7.*
```

On RHEL 8, `/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/versionlock.list` contains:

```
# File managed by puppet
0:puppet-agent-0:6.16.0-*
```

My understanding is the `yum versionlock` doesn't care about the version listed in the file - just the package name.

I looked into whether puppet can clear the version lock, run the update, and set the version lock again all in the same agent run, but I can't find any way to make that work.

Any other way to do this?

We are running RHEL7 and RHEL8, and using the official Puppet YUM repositories.

Comment: Are you using [puppet's own yum repo](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/puppet_platform.html#enable_the_puppet_platform_repository)?

Comment: @MichaelHampton We are running RHEL7 and RHEL8, and using the official Puppet YUM repositories

Comment: Hm. You may want to check what was actually written to the `/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/versionlock.list` file and see if it matches your intentions.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Added to question